# Elasticsearch term filter on inner object field not matching

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I have just organized my document structure to have a more OO design (e.g. moved top level properties like `venueId` and `venueName` into a `venue` object with `id` and `name` fields).

However I can now not get a simple term filter working for fields on the child `venue` inner object.

Here is my mapping:

```
{
    "deal": {
        "properties": {
            "textId": {"type":"string","name":"textId","index":"no"},
            "displayId": {"type":"string","name":"displayId","index":"no"},
            "active": {"name":"active","type":"boolean","index":"not_analyzed"},
            "venue": {
                "type":"object",
                "path":"full",
                "properties": {
                    "textId": {"type":"string","name":"textId","index":"not_analyzed"},
                    "regionId": {"type":"string","name":"regionId","index":"not_analyzed"},
                    "displayId": {"type":"string","name":"displayId","index":"not_analyzed"},
                    "name": {"type":"string","name":"name"},
                    "address": {"type":"string","name":"address"},
                    "area": {
                        "type":"multi_field",
                        "fields": {
                            "area": {"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
                            "area_search": {"type":"string","index":"analyzed"}}},
                    "location": {"type":"geo_point","lat_lon":true}}},
            "tags": {
                "type":"multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "tags":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
                    "tags_search":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed"}}},
            "days": {
                "type":"multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "days":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
                    "days_search":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed"}}},
            "value": {"type":"string","name":"value"},
            "title": {"type":"string","name":"title"},
            "subtitle": {"type":"string","name":"subtitle"},
            "description": {"type":"string","name":"description"},
            "time": {"type":"string","name":"time"},
            "link": {"type":"string","name":"link","index":"no"},
            "previewImage": {"type":"string","name":"previewImage","index":"no"},
            "detailImage": {"type":"string","name":"detailImage","index":"no"}}}
}
```

Here is an example document:

```
GET /production/deals/wa-au-some-venue-weekends-some-deal

{
    "_index":"some-index-v1",
    "_type":"deals",
    "_id":"wa-au-some-venue-weekends-some-deal",
    "_version":1,
    "exists":true, 
    "_source" : {
        "id":"921d5fe0-8867-4d5c-81b4-7c1caf11325f",
        "textId":"wa-au-some-venue-weekends-some-deal",
        "displayId":"some-venue-weekends-some-deal",
        "active":true,
        "venue":{
            "id":"46a7cb64-395c-4bc4-814a-a7735591f9de",
            "textId":"wa-au-some-venue",
            "regionId":"wa-au",
            "displayId":"some-venue",
            "name":"Some Venue",
            "address":"sdgfdg",
            "area":"Swan Valley & Surrounds"},
        "tags":["Lunch"],
        "days":["Saturday","Sunday"],
        "value":"$1",
        "title":"Some Deal",
        "subtitle":"",
        "description":"",
        "time":"5pm - Late"
    }
}
```

And here is an 'explain' test on that same document:

```
POST /production/deals/wa-au-some-venue-weekends-some-deal/_explain

{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "venue.regionId": "wa-au"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "ok":true,
    "_index":"some-index-v1",
    "_type":"deals",
    "_id":"wa-au-some-venue-weekends-some-deal",
    "matched":false,
    "explanation":{
        "value":0.0,
        "description":"ConstantScore(cache(venue.regionId:wa-au)) doesn't match id 0"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get more useful debugging info?
Is there something wrong with the explain result description? Simply saying "doesn't match id 0" does not really make sense to me... the field is called 'regionId' (not 'id') and the value is definitely not 0...???

Comment: How come the index says "production" from your POST statement /production/deals/wa-au-some-venue-weekends-some-deal/ but says "some_index_v1" from the GET request? (I'm also removing my answer so it hopefully gets more attention.)

Comment: @ramseykhalaf production is just an alias for the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because the type you submitted the mapping for is called `deal`, while the type you indexed the document in is called `deals`.

If you look at the mapping for your type `deals`, you'll see that was automatically generated and the field venue.regionId is analyzed, thus you most likely have two tokens in your index: `wa` and `au`. Only searching for those tokens on that type you would get back that document.

Anything else looks just great! Only a small character is wrong ;)

Comment: ****facepalm**** - thankyou!!! You have no idea how long I stared at that trying to work out what was wrong, testing out all sorts of crazy hypotheses around inner object field paths and how they might cause differences... such a simple thing in the end, as per usual :)
Still... the debugging experience left a lot to be desired. Surely ES could have told me during the explain operation that 'regionId:wa-au' didnt match tokens 'wa' or 'au'? That would at least have gave me the hint that it was performing the default analysis and so prob wasn't using my mapping...

Comment: I can imagine! Well...it actually did tell you the doc wasn't matching your `venue.regionId:wa-au` filter, you probably got distracted by the id 0 in the explain output, which is the lucene internal doc id. Just trust elasticsearch...if it tells you something doesn't match, there is a good reason for that :)